# Add more effect on div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello friends i want to add more effects on my div when i click on the `<li>` my code is working perfect [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7mRx/) but i want to add effect like `fadeIn()` `fadeOut()` and `slideup()` and `slideDown()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then why don't you do it? You seem to know how to use jQuery methods? See: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ for an example.

Comment: @user1302513 , it would be great if you elaborate it a bit more..What or which div should fadein() fadeout()

Comment: tried but its not working perfect i want that current text go with fadeIn() effect and next content come with fadeOut() effect 

http://jsfiddle.net/m7mRx/1/

Comment: freebird i want #fade to be fadein or fadeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[You could do something like this:](http://jsfiddle.net/m7mRx/6/)***

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<div id="selected">cvb</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#selected {
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    border:solid;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:2em;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul li {
    margin:2px 0;
    padding:10px;
    background:#999999;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    width:90%;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

ul li:hover {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    color:black;
}​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    var $selected = $("#selected");
    $("ul li").click(function() {

        var $li = $(this);
        $selected
            .stop(true,true)
            .fadeOut(0)
            .html($li.html())
            .fadeIn(2000);

    });

});
​
```

Comment: @user1302513 - No problem =D Don't forget to upvote all the answers you like as well as selecting one as the accepted answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the functions as such:

```
$('#fade').fadeOut().fadeIn().html(p);
```

Every "effect" will be active after the other one has "acted".
To ensure that there wont be a mass loop of effects, I recommend using the .stop() function.

as so:(to see the difference, click many times on the li and try the code with and without the .stop() function).

```
$('#fade').stop().fadeOut().fadeIn().html(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ,

```
$('#lione').click(function () {
    var p = $('#one').html();
    $('#fade').stop().slideUp(1000).slideDown(1000).html(p);
})

$('#litwo').click(function () {
    var p = $('#two').html();
    $('#fade').slideUp(1000).slideDown(1000).html(p);
    $('#fade').html(p);
})
```